# How can I play an arrayBuffer as an audio file?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am receiving an arrayBuffer via a socket.io event and want to be able to process and play the stream as an audio file.

I am receiving the buffer like so:

```
retrieveAudioStream = () => {
  this.socket.on('stream', (arrayBuffer) => {
    console.log('arrayBuffer', arrayBuffer)
  })
}
```

Is it possible to set the `src` attribute of an `<audio/>` element to a buffer? If not how can I play the the incoming buffer stream?

edit:

To show how I am getting my audio input and streaming it:

```
window.navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, this.initializeRecorder, this.handleError);



initializeRecorder = (stream) => {
    const audioContext = window.AudioContext;
    const context = new audioContext();
    const audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const bufferSize = 2048;
    // create a javascript node
    const recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
    // specify the processing function
    recorder.onaudioprocess = this.recorderProcess;
    // connect stream to our recorder
    audioInput.connect(recorder);
    // connect our recorder to the previous destination
    recorder.connect(context.destination);
  }
```

This is where I receive the inputBuffer event and stream via a socket.io event

```
  recorderProcess = (e) => {
    const left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    this.socket.emit('stream', this.convertFloat32ToInt16(left))
  }
```

EDIT 2:
Adding Raymonds suggestion:

```
retrieveAudioStream = () => {

  const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();

  this.socket.on('stream', (buffer) => {

    const b = audioContext.createBuffer(1, buffer.length, audioContext.sampleRate); 
    b.copyToChannel(buffer, 0, 0)
    const s = audioContext.createBufferSource(); 
    s.buffer = b

  })
}
```

Getting error: `NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'createBuffer' on 'BaseAudioContext': The number of frames provided (0) is less than or equal to the minimum bound (0).`

Comment: Depends on what sort of data is in the array buffer. Do you know what the format of the data is?

Comment: I believe it is an Int16 arrayBuffer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: what api is in use?  you might want to review this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource

Comment: @RobertRowntree I have added code to show how I am receiving audio input and how I am streaming it

Comment: I think the error message is clear.  `buffer.length is 0` and that's not allowed when creating an `AudioBuffer`.  Sorry, you get to figure this out, because I can't tell from the code why it is 0.

Comment: @RaymondToy the error states `The number of frames` so I'm a bit confused as to where you get `buffer.length` from? Even doing checking to ensure `buffer.length` is greater than 0 before creating buffer, throws the aforementioned error. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: `audioContext.createBuffer(1, buffer.length, audioContext.sampleRate);`  The second arg, `buffer.length`, is the number of frames.  If you know that `buffer.length` is not 0 here, then I don't understand what's going on.  Maybe the error message is from somewhere else where you're creating an `AudioBuffer`?

Comment: Hi @stretch0, I met the same problem too, did you solved the problem above? Would you mind to share your codes for how to transfer the Int16Array to websocket and play the audio? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Did you able to resolve this issue? If so could you please share your code? I am stuck at same place.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick read of what `initializeRecorder` and `recorderProcess` do, it looks like you're converting the float32 samples to int16 in some say and that gets sent to `retrieveAudioStream` in some way.

If this is correct, then the arrayBuffer is an array of int16 values.  Convert them to float32 (most likely by dividing each value by 32768) and save them in a Float32Array.  Then create an `AudioBuffer` of the same lenght and `copyToChannel(float32Array, 0, 0)` to write the values to the `AudioBuffer`.  Use an `AudioBufferSourceNode` with this buffer to play out the audio.

Comment: This sounds plausible but I am struggling to understand how to create the AudioBuffer and copyToChannel parts fit in. Let's assume I have a float32 array, would you mind showing a code example of how to do the rest?

Comment: Let `f32` be the `Float32Array`. Create the `AudioBuffer`:`b = audioContext.createBuffer(1, f32.length, audioContext.sampleRate); b.copyToChannel(f32, 0, 0)`.  Use it in a source: `s = audioContext.createBufferSource(); s.buffer = b`

Comment: I have added your suggestion but getting an error.I have added an edit to my original post to show how I have implemented it. Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to find any info on that error.

Comment: Is there a working code snippet for this. Working on this and stuck :(

Comment: Best approach right now is to create a small example using jsfiddle.net or codepen.io.  Then I can take a look and maybe make suggestions.